# Do I have to declare a category for all private methods of a class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c-category

Suppose I want to have a private method of a class to be visible to the implementation of that class only so that the class' interface exposes only what needs to be exposed. In some recent versions of Xcode, I can do this simply by omitting the method's declaration in the header. However, one good book suggests that I should also declare a category in the implementation file and declare that method within it, like this:

```
// [in MyClass.m]
#import "MyClass.h"

// category declaration - is it really required?
// edit: it's a class extension declaration, I know, but it doesn't change much
@interface MyClass ()
- (void)myPrivateMethod;
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (void)myPrivateMethod
{
    // do something
}
// all methods here can call myPrivateMethod
@end
```

Indeed it does compile and work. Moreover, it does compile and work fine without the category/extension declaration part. This rises a natural question:

If I have a bunch of private methods, do I need to declare all of them in a category? What would be the best practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This is not a *category*, it's a *class extension*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html) (note that there is no category name, the parentheses are empty).

It is a very good idea to add your private methods to a class extension. Doing so ensures that all methods have declarations, and that these declarations are visible only to the parts of your code where you want them to be visible.

Note that unlike ordinary categories, class extensions let you add instance variables. This is very convenient when your implementation relies on classes that are not part of the interface of your class.

Comment: I knew it was an extension, just got used calling it _nameless category_ in my mind. Quitting this habit..

Comment: LOL The term *category* never struck me as overly descriptive for some reason; that's why I keep thinking of categories as of "named extensions" :)

Comment: I'd suggest turning on "don't allow method implementations without prior declarations" and forcing yourself to use the extension to declare all private methods.  Makes it much easier to quickly remind yourself of the implementation details.

Comment: @bbum Thank you very much for a great tip, I did not know the option to check this already exists! I'll be turning it on on all my projects from now on, I'm sure it'll help me find a missing declaration or two :)

Comment: @OscarGomez An extension is more than an anonymous category, because it lets you add instance variables to your class; named categories do not let you do that.

Comment: @OscarGomez It's other way around: An _extension_ is (_much like_) a _category_, just without the name.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ..so is that option located somewhere in the build settings or just in our messy heads? (I'd prefer the former)

Comment: @bbum I searched for the option in the compiler settings, but the closest that I was able to find was "treat missing function prototypes as errors". Turning it on did not catch missing method declarations. Could you please let me know the name of that compiler option?

Comment: @DesmondHume I don't know yet, I've asked bbum for the name of the option.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Well, forget it then. I think what he meant was mere self-discipline.

Comment: GCC_WARN_UNDECLARED_SELECTOR -- "undeclared selectors" in the settings inspector.  This is a related and useful weblog post.  See the comments.  http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2009-11-07/warnings